# C++ noexcept operator

Tags: c++, constexpr, noexcept

```
// Base class for noexcept testing
class MyNoExcept
{
public:
    void Func() noexcept
    {}

    void Func1()
    {}
};

// Derived class for noexcept testing
class MyNoExcept2 : public MyNoExcept
{
public:
    void Func2() noexcept(noexcept(MyNoExcept::Func()))
    {
        static_assert(noexcept(MyNoExcept::Func()), "MyNoExcept::Func() must be noexcept");
    }
    // incorrect specification of function Func1!
    void Func3() noexcept(noexcept(static_cast<MyNoExcept*>(this)->Func1)) 
    {
        static_assert(noexcept(static_cast<MyNoExcept*>(this)->Func1), "MyNoExcept::Func1() must be noexcept");
    }
};

// Test function
void TestNoexcept()
{
    MyNoExcept2 m;
    m.Func2();

    // error C2056: illegal expression
    if constexpr (noexcept(MyNoExcept::Func()))
    {
        printf("MyNoExcept::Func() is noexcept\n");
    }

    m.Func3();
}
```

Here is a code example that I tried to compile with VC++ VS 2022 (Community Edition). I have 2 questions about the behavior of the `noexcept` operator:

1. Clearly, `noexcept(MyNoExcept::Func())` is a compile time expression. Why does the `constexpr if` statement not compile?
2. `Func3` above uses incorrect specification for a function `MyNoExcept::Func1` (no parameters) in the `noexcept` declaration and the ~static_assert~. But code compiles and produces impression of safety.

I am expecting `if constexpr (noexcept(MyNoExcept::Func()))` to be compiled. I am expecting ~void Func3() noexcept(noexcept(static_cast<MyNoExcept*>(this)->Func1))` to cause an error.

Comment: The noexcept keyword is a property of a function, like 'const" and plays a role in function overloading. Then there is noexcept(fn(args_t...)) which will evaluate to true if  function fn(args_t...) has a been declared to be noexcept (with args being the parameter types of the function). Hope that helps. This : `noexcept(noexcept(MyNoExcept::Func()))` at least makes no sense (to me).

Comment: `incorrect specification of function Func1!` what is incorrect about it? What error do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

The argument of `noexcept()` operator needs to be expression. Member function alone is not an expression outside of the class. It lacks an object to call the function on. This should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
class MyNoExcept
{
public:
    void Func() noexcept
    {}

    void Func1()
    {}
};

// Derived class for noexcept testing
class MyNoExcept2 : public MyNoExcept
{
public:
    void Func2() noexcept(noexcept(MyNoExcept::Func()))
    {
        static_assert(noexcept(MyNoExcept::Func()), "MyNoExcept::Func() must be noexcept");
    }
    // incorrect specification of function Func1!
    void Func3() noexcept(noexcept(static_cast<MyNoExcept*>(this)->Func1)) 
    {
        static_assert(noexcept(static_cast<MyNoExcept*>(this)->Func1), "MyNoExcept::Func1() must be noexcept");
    }
};

// Test function
void TestNoexcept()
{
    MyNoExcept2 m;
    m.Func2();

    // error C2056: illegal expression
    if constexpr (noexcept(MyNoExcept().Func()))
    {
        printf("MyNoExcept::Func() is noexcept\n");
    }

    m.Func3();
}

int main()
{
    TestNoexcept();
}
```

Member function of base class fully qualified inside class code is expression. So inside class you don't need to say `this->MyNoExcept::Func()` plain `MyNoExcept::Func()` is good enough to qualify as expression.

The `static_cast<MyNoExcept*>(this)->Func1` is expression of type pointer to member function. As there are no user-defined throwing `MyNoExcept::operator->*` overloads the result is `noexcept(true)`.

I do not know of tool that gives a warning in templated context that what you maybe want to check is not if `MyNoExcept::operator->*` is allowed to throw. Tools are not psychic and C++ developers can use quite arcane constructs in template context.

Comment: Thank you for explanation related to constexpr if statement. This address my first question. However, I am still puzeled with second question. The declaration void Func3() noexcept(noexcept(static_cast<MyNoExcept*>(this)->Func1)) misses parenthesis. I use 'static_cast' with 'this' because similar situation might appear in template class that implements static polymorphism. I even more surprised that 'static_assert' inside Func3 compiles. It does not work as expected, but it creates false sense safety.

Comment: Oh that. I add some sentences at that problem as well.